# Extracting a merged assembly from an existing assembly in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I've inherited a C# .NET assembly that has two merged assemblies wrapped within it. I need to extract those assemblies - in effect, an "un-ILMerge," but I've not found such a tool. Does such a beast actually exist?

Comment: Are you sure they're merged as modules and not embedded resources?

Comment: Oooh - good question. Honest answer? No, not sure.

Comment: Open the assembly in ILSpy.

Comment: BAAAH...Blast it all. Not even a module - just two embedded namespaces within the assembly. ILSpy did the trick....well, told me what I thought I knew was wrong. Alas. Thanks for the suggestion @Slaks!